# How can I pan a webview in google glass

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm working on a Google Glass app that uses a webview.

In the standard Google Glass browser, you can place two fingers on the touchpad and move your head around to pan the webpage. It also overlays a crosshairs that can be used to select links.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to programmatically enable the head controlled panning and display the cross hairs within a webview? Has anybody come across an api that allows this?

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's a feature of the built in browser. You can request that such a feature be available in the GDK [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/) otherwise I would suggest simply sending an intent to the built in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I needed to keep control within the app so sending an intent to a browser was not a viable option. I did however follow your advice and submit a feature request to Google.

Comment: @Smalesy An accepted answer would be appreciated (and would help your stats too).

Answer (score 0):

As said above, this is a feature of the built-in browser.  The default WebView doesn't have the cross-hairs overlay, nor does it detect Gestures.  You may have to implement a GestureListener and have it send Javascript events using loadUrl().

Here's a link to the SDK For GestureListeners:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/touch

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround on how to do this: https://github.com/mikesmales/GoogleGlassCrosshairs